# Generalization of Schwarz-Pick Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\in H(B(0,1))$, $f(B(0,1))\subset B(0,1)$. Suppose all distinct zeros of the function in the unit disk are $z_1,...,z_n$, with order $k_1,...,k_n$. Show that $\forall z\in B(0,1)$,

$|f(z)| \le \prod_{j=1}^n {|\frac {z_j-z}{1-\bar {z}_j z}|}^{k_j}$.

---

I used Schwarz-Pick Lemma and got $|f(z)| \le |\frac {z_j-z}{1-\bar {z}_j z}|$. But then how to put them together?

Thank you!

Comment: What can you say about the function $$g \colon z \mapsto f(z)\cdot \prod_{j = 1}^n \biggl(\frac{1 - \overline{z_j}\,z}{z_j-z}\biggr)^{k_j}\,?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer it has no zeros in the unit disk, so the max module of $g$ should be taken on boundary, where the Blaschke product has module 1, but how can I judge whether the module of $f$ on boundary is smaller than 1?

Comment: $f$ need not have a continuous extension to the boundary, so we can't just plug boundary values into $f$, we need a slightly more indirect approach, taking the limit of the behaviour on $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert = r\}$ as $r \to 1$. Well, we have the hypothesis that $f(B(0,1)) \subset B(0,1)$, so …

Comment: @DanielFischer oh, I understand. Because holomorphism implies open mapping theorem, so $Im(f)\subset B(0,r)\subset B(0,1)$. Then max module theorem works! Thank you!

Comment: In general, we don't have $f(B(0,1)) \subset B(0,r)$. The idea is that for $\lvert z\rvert = r$, we have $$\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant \frac{\sup \{ \lvert f(\zeta)\rvert : \lvert\zeta\rvert = r\}}{\inf \{ \lvert P(\zeta)\rvert : \lvert \zeta\rvert = r\}} \leqslant \frac{1}{\inf \{ \lvert P(\zeta)\rvert : \lvert \zeta\rvert = r\}},$$ where $P$ is the Blaschke product. Since $P$ is continuous on the boundary, we have $\lim\limits_{r\to 1} \inf \{ \lvert P(\zeta)\rvert : \dotsc\} = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer your solution is right. But I wonder why $f(B(0,1))\subset B(0,r)$ is wrong. Since the unit disk is open, for every point on the boundary of the image of $f$, has a neighborhood contained in the unit disk. Then because this boundary is bounded and closed, thus compact, and has Heine-Borel property that we can select finite small disk to cover it. Then it is easily noticed that there exists such a $B(0,r)$ covering the image if $f$. I remember that is a classical way of considering analytical extension.

Comment: Consider $f(z) = z$ for example. We have $f(B(0,1)) \subset B(0,r)$ for some $r < 1$ if the boundary of $f(B(0,1))$ is contained in $B(0,1)$, but usually, the boundary of the former intersects the boundary of the latter.

Comment: Oh, thank you. You are right.